# CSS Animation changes the element position

Tags: css, svg, css-animations, svg-animate

I have a hexagon inside a circle.

See the initial scenario: https://jsfiddle.net/njzwfvpf/

Now I want to add an animation rotating the hexagon 360deg inside the circle

This is the existing scenario with the css animation ([fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/vp3y0fpz/)):

```css
.rotate {
  -webkit-animation: rotating 3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1) infinite alternate;
          animation: rotating 3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1) infinite alternate;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
          transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotating {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="350" height="350">
  <svg width="350" height="350">
    <circle cx="230.00591443779982" cy="155.55555555555554" r="45" style="stroke: rgb(158, 157, 158); stroke-width: 1; fill: none;"></circle>
    <circle cx="100" cy="155.55555555555554" r="45" style="stroke: rgb(158, 157, 158); stroke-width: 1; fill: none;"></circle>
    <circle cx="180.41237113402062" cy="155.55555555555554" r="50" style="stroke: rgb(158, 157, 158); stroke-width: 1; fill: none;"></circle>
    <circle cx="165.0943396226415" cy="120.27491408934708" r="45" style="stroke: rgb(158, 157, 158); stroke-width: 1; fill: none;"></circle>
    <circle cx="165.0943396226415" cy="200" r="45" style="stroke: rgb(158, 157, 158); stroke-width: 1; fill: none;"></circle>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 600 720" width="295" height="205">
      <g transform="translate(239, 370)" class="rotate">
        <path></path>
        <path d="M 175 0 L 326.55444566227675 87.50000000000001 L 326.55444566227675 262.5 L 175 350 L 23.445554337723223 262.5 L 23.44555433772325 87.49999999999999" style="opacity: 0.4; fill: black;"></path>
      </g>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 600 720" width="507.4" height="799.5">
        <g transform="translate(105, 395)">
          <path d="M 175 0 L 341.43489035165186 120.9220259843842 L 277.8624191511828 316.57797401561584 L 72.13758084881722 316.57797401561584 L 8.565109648348141 120.92202598438415" style="opacity: 0.4; fill: black;"></path>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </svg>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

The problem is that adding the animation the Hexagon changes its position,  it is not inside the circle nanymore.

What am I doing wrong ? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue you are facing is that you are applying a transform with *CSS* (`rotate(360deg)`) while you already have a transform on the same element in the SVG (`translate(239, 370)`). You can solve this with 2 approaches :

1. apply all the transforms with *CSS* so you can control the animation with *CSS*
2. apply the *CSS* animation on the child element (the hexagon)

Here is an example of how you can solve it with the second approach :

```css
.rotate {
  -webkit-animation: rotating 3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1) infinite alternate;
          animation: rotating 3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1) infinite alternate;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
          transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotating {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="350" height="350">
  <svg width="350" height="350">
    <circle cx="230.00591443779982" cy="155.55555555555554" r="45" style="stroke: rgb(158, 157, 158); stroke-width: 1; fill: none;"></circle>
    <circle cx="100" cy="155.55555555555554" r="45" style="stroke: rgb(158, 157, 158); stroke-width: 1; fill: none;"></circle>
    <circle cx="180.41237113402062" cy="155.55555555555554" r="50" style="stroke: rgb(158, 157, 158); stroke-width: 1; fill: none;"></circle>
    <circle cx="165.0943396226415" cy="120.27491408934708" r="45" style="stroke: rgb(158, 157, 158); stroke-width: 1; fill: none;"></circle>
    <circle cx="165.0943396226415" cy="200" r="45" style="stroke: rgb(158, 157, 158); stroke-width: 1; fill: none;"></circle>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 600 720" width="295" height="205">
      <g transform="translate(239, 370)">
        <path></path>
        <path class="rotate" d="M 175 0 L 326.55444566227675 87.50000000000001 L 326.55444566227675 262.5 L 175 350 L 23.445554337723223 262.5 L 23.44555433772325 87.49999999999999" style="opacity: 0.4; fill: black;"></path>
      </g>
      <svg viewBox="0 0 600 720" width="507.4" height="799.5">
        <g transform="translate(105, 395)">
          <path d="M 175 0 L 341.43489035165186 120.9220259843842 L 277.8624191511828 316.57797401561584 L 72.13758084881722 316.57797401561584 L 8.565109648348141 120.92202598438415" style="opacity: 0.4; fill: black;"></path>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </svg>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: Maybe this solution might have worked in past but when I hit the Run code snippet here in your solution, it is having same issue where polygon is not rotating inside the circle. I have same issue with my svg rotate animation. Also in my case there is no such transforms applied initially and I just applied using CSS on the child element directly but output is not as expected like in this case. After trying hard to resolve I even switched from rotate to scale animation in design but same issue faced. The center position of element is changing with these animations. So how can we resolve it?