# CSS Animation changes position fixed <img> when applying animation to <main> element

Tags: css, dom, css-position

I have a `<main>` tag and inside that `<main>` tag I have a `<img>` tag with `position: fixed;`.
And as soon as I apply the animation to the `<main>` tag it moves the image to inside the container even if I have `position: fixed;` applied.

I have honestly no clue. It shouldn't move due to having position fixed right?

I have made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wechag8o/2/) so you can see the whole thing in action.

As soon as I comment the animation in the scss it works and the image stays fixed on the left bottom.

And I can't edit the html structure on the actual page I'm working on.
I can only edit the css.
Also no JavaScript is allowed either so only CSS is available.

**HTML:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <main>
      <img class="side-shadow" src="https://collection.ju.mp/assets/images/gallery18/ab27fde1_original.gif" />
      <h1 id="content">Content</h1>
    </main>
  </body>

</html>
```

**SCSS:**

```css
main {
  
  /* Comment this animation to fix it but that's not what I want since I want the animation on the main element.
     And I cannot change the document html on the actual page I'm working on. I can only change the CSS.
  */
  animation: floating 2s infinite ease-in-out;

  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 20%);
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

@keyframes floating {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateY(5px);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
}

.side-shadow {
    position: fixed;
    left: 10px;
    object-fit: contain;
    bottom: 10px;
    max-height: 400px;
    z-index: -2;
}

#content {
  text-align: center;
}
```

**JS:**

```js
const contentElement = document.querySelector("#content");
const mainElement = document.querySelector("main");

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  const clone = contentElement.cloneNode(true);
  mainElement.appendChild(clone);
}
```

I have not tried anything else other than to just remove the animation for now.
I did look at [this StackOverflow Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39959506/css-animation-changes-the-element-position) but I couldn't solve it.

I'm honestly clueless on how to fix this other than to just have no animation at all.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.